# multiple markers with url

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using Google Maps API with multiple markers & mouse over & infowindows. It works perfectly. Now I want to add an individual URL for each marker on CLICK. But for some reason, all markers always open the last URL. - What is possibly the problem?

```js
     // Define your locations: HTML content for mouseover, the info window content, latitude, longitude, url
     var locations = [
      ['<h8>Brugg</h8>', '<h7>auseinander.</h7>', 47.4867355, 8.2109103, 'http://www.stadtereignisse.ch/dokumentiert/'],

      ['<h8>Aarau»</h8>', '<h7>Aarau</h7>', 47.391224, 8.038669, 'http://www.stadtereignisse.ch/erlebt/'],

      ['<h8>Bern</h8>', '<h7>Bern</h7>', 46.947974, 7.447447, 'http://www.stadtereignisse.ch/erwuenscht/']
     ];
```

```js
     // Add the markers and infowindows to the map
     for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]),
        /*  title: locations[i][0],  */
  url: "http://www.stadtereignisse.ch/dokumentiert/",
         map: map,
         visible: true,
         icon: icons[iconCounter]
       });
 
       markers.push(marker);
 

       
 
 // CLICK (Allow each marker to have an info window)
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    window.location.href = marker.url;
});



  // MOUSEOVER      
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));           
       
       
       
       iconCounter++;
       // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so we may have to restart the counter
       if(iconCounter >= iconsLength) {
        iconCounter = 0;
       }
     }
```

Comment: is it me or you have hardcoded the url in your `for` loop ? Seems you're always using 'http://www.stadtereignisse.ch/dokumentiert/' (and please edit your post it is really bad indented)

Comment: Thanks for your comment ValLeNain!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the difference between your `click` handler and your `mouseover` handler. One of these creates a closure; the other does not. You need to create a closure for `click` as well.

However, instead of the complicated technique of a function-that-returns-a-function, there is a cleaner way to do it. Simply move the entire loop body into one function that you call from the loop. Then you won't need the extra complication on the mouseover (or click either).

Also, as @ValLeNain pointed out, you're setting `marker.url` to a hard coded value instead of a different value for each marker, so I changed that to what looks like the value you want.

Finally, a bit of user experience advice: I *do not recommend* opening an infowindow on a mouseover. As you have probably noticed, if you open an infowindow for a marker near the top of the visible map, the entire map shifts to bring the infowindow into view. It is confusing and surprising when a mouseover triggers that movement. Infowindows should be opened on a click, not a mouseover. Then if you want to put a link inside the infowindow text you can do that.

I didn't address this issue in the code below, but will leave it for you to sort out.

```
    // Add the markers and infowindows to the map
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      addMarker( locations[i] );
    }

    function addMarker( location ) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[2], location[3]),
        title: location[0],
        url: location[4],
        map: map,
        visible: true,
        icon: icons[iconCounter]
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      // CLICK (Allow each marker to have an info window)
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          window.location.href = marker.url;
      });

      // MOUSEOVER      
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(location[0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });

      iconCounter++;
      // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so we may have to restart the counter
      if(iconCounter >= iconsLength) {
        iconCounter = 0;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Michael, that is amazing, thank you so much! It works absolutely perfectly. I am very grateful.
I know that opening the infowindow on mouseover shifts the map, but for now we have decided to handle it like this, as for the total layout of our page it makes sense. Thanks for the hint anyway!

Comment: just set `disableAutoPan` to `true` to avoid this ;) (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=fr#InfoWindowOptions)